# QGIS 2.0 and Debian Jessie

Tags: qgis, linux

I added the official QGIS repos to my installation of Debian Jessie using the instructions on the official QGIS page. As of now, there appears to be some packages missing from the repos that resolve dependencies required by the package.

The following is the output for the aptitude:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-qgis : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libqgis2.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
 qgis : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
        Depends: libqgis2.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 2.0.1-3+jessie1) but it is not going to be installed
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libqgis2.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: grass642 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

For those of you curious about what my sources.list looks like:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

#QGIS
deb     http://qgis.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian jessie main
```

The culprit appears to be libgdal1, does anyone have a solution for this outside of compiling all the dependencies by hand?

Comment: it sounds like you have various mixed sources. Try to (1) remove everything related to qgis (2) only insert the Dafour-jessi sources into your sources.list and (3) reinstall `sudo apt-get install qgis`

Comment: Double checking my sources did not fix the broken dependency libgdal1 is still unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for anyone in a similar situation. The libgdal1 dependency is unresolved in testing at the moment, and will be for a short bit(references:[here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-gis/2014/01/msg00000.html), [and here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-gis/2013/12/msg00017.html)). A quick and dirty solution is just to temporarily utilize the nightly builds of QGIS until the bug is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Brother, i had the same problem 5 minutes ago and resolved:

FIRST
I install grass

When i did

```
sudo apt-get install grass grass-doc
```

[Reference](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Installation_Guide)

Console says i need to install grasss-gui and grass-core, so

```
sudo apt-get install grass grass-doc grass-gui grass-core
```

and GOAL

Then i just write

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis
```

Which installed qgis, but the 1,75 version, so i followed the qgis instruction with the keys

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 47765B75
gpg --export --armor 47765B75 | sudo apt-key add -
```

The i added the sources

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add

```
deb     http://qgis.org/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian wheezy main
```

Then the usuall

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

and QGIS 2,2

Here is the [image: proof]

Regards!